# Can an overriden method be statically analyzed?

Tags: c#, oop, static-analysis

Given this situation:

```
interface Interfaz 
{
        void M1();
}

abstract class ClaseAbstracta : Interfaz
{
    public void M1() { }
    public abstract Boolean M2();
}

class ClaseConcreta : ClaseAbstracta 
{
    public override Boolean M2() { return false; }
    public virtual void M3(Int32 i) { }
    public void M4() { }
}
```

I also do:

```
ClaseConcreta concretaCast = (ClaseConcreta) abst;
```

Could `concretaCast.M2()` be analysed statically?

For one, it has `override` so it seems as it couldn't but when you see `M2()` it actually is the concrete implementation.

So is this statically analyzable or every time it has override it has to do it during run-time dynamically?

Comment: Static animalization: illegal in 26 states.

Comment: Maybe he is a [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animalize) fan ^^

Comment: @Trufa: why do you think it shouldn't?

Comment: Really people :) languages are written using an english like syntax, use english please!!! Reading something like "interface Interfaz" or "class GestoreTicketOspedalieri" makes me crazy!

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti yeah, this isn't my code, it is a code example from my university.  I was too lazy to translate... sorry :=

Comment: @Tigran shouldn't what? dynamically or statically?

Comment: @Trufa: I mean why you doubt this code can fail on static checking ?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that this can be statically analyzed in the general case. Consider:

```
class ClaseConcreta2 : ClaseConcreta
{
    public override Boolean M2() { return true; }
}

void Main()
{
    var x = new ClaseConcreta2();
    DoSomething(x);
}

void DoSomething(ClassAbstracta abst)
{
    ClaseConcreta concretaCast = (ClaseConcreta) abst;
    // okay, so it's a ClaseConcreta, but what kind?
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what is your point, `var x` will be `ClaseConcreta2()` and you will be able to pass it as a parameter because of the cast. But I'm not really sure what you are trying to show me... sorry :(

Comment: @Trufa: My example is another way of saying what you said in your answer.

Comment: Hmm I think I got it now. +1. Thanks for the answer, good example, I will keep reading and maybe accept it later. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It **could** be sometimes:

```
void DoNothingReally(ClaseAbstracta x)
{
  ClaseConcreta y = new ClaseConcreta();
  y.M2(); // Only possibly the implementation from ClaseConcreta.
  ClaseAbstracta abst = y;
  ClaseConcreta concretaCast = (ClaseConcreta) abst;
  concretaCast.M2(); // Only possibly the implemenation from ClaseConcreta, but more work to figure this out.
  x.M2(); // can't know where the implentation is from generally, but see below
}
void DoMoreNothing()
{
  DoNothingReally(new ClaseConcreta());//the call x.M2() above will only possibly the implemenation from ClaseConcreta but lots of work to figure that out.
}
```

Now, another question is whether anything actually **will** determine this. In writing about C++, Bjarne Stroustrup talks about the fact that compilers can replace virtual calls with non-virtual calls as an optimisation. I've no idea how much that is done in C++, never mind if anything does it with C#. It is theoretically possible though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

I will be dynamic and analyzed in run-time.

The reason being that override is also a virtual method since any that inherits from that class, could also override.